# How can I get a typedef void* value in Java?

Tags: java, jna

I have a dll that is written in C.
I have to implement the code that will use this dll in Java,
but I don't quite understand the meaning of the given h file.

```
 typedef void* wqctl_handle;

 wqctl_handle _stdcall wqctl_connect (const  char* SettFile, const  char* SettSec, const char* name, const char* pwd);
```

What is this `wqctl_handle` return type applicable to Java and how to work with it correctly? (I understand that I should use JNA, but my experience is not enough to understand this)

I managed to implement something like this:

```
 public interface Qmonitor extends StdCallLibrary {

    Qmonitor INSTANCE = (Qmonitor) Native.load(new File("").getAbsolutePath() + "\\ClientAPI.dll", Qmonitor.class);

    int wqctl_connect(String settFile, String settSec, String name, String pwd);
}
```

According to the documentation, this method should return either a connection descriptor or 0. But I get an error:

```
java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeInt(Native Method)
```

Comment: JNA has a [`Pointer`](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.10.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Pointer.html) class, which represents all pointers. Under the hood, it’s just a wrapper for a Java `long`. If you wanted to use JNI directly, you would cast it to a `jlong` as well, or `jint` on 32-bit platforms.

Comment: Your native method is returning 64-bit Pointer and you're trying to squeeze it into a 32-bit `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JNA [Mappings](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/Mappings.md) documentation points out that `void *` maps to a `Pointer` in JNA.  Pointer size is OS bitness dependent, 32-bit on 32-bit systems and 64-bit on 64-bit systems.

By including a return type of `int` you are requiring the return value to fit into 32 bits.  However, you are executing on a 64-bit operating system and getting the error when JNA attempts to store 8 bytes into a 4-byte memory allocation.

While the `Pointer` class itself will work as a return value and is a low-level general purpose pointer, it is common practice to use the `PointerType` class for type-safe pointers.  In this case you could write:

```java
class WqctlHandle extends PointerType {}
```

Then you could pass that type safe `WqctlHandle` pointer to other methods as needed.   You could also add code inside that class to implement functions using that pointer as an argument, e.g. include a `doFoo()` method inside that class that calls `Qmonitor.INSTANCE.doFoo(wcqtl_handle ptr);`